# Primitive Array initialization without value?

Tags: java, arrays, primitive, primitive-types

I just found a random code snippet:

```
int[] i = new int[]{0,};
```

How is this even possible?

Primitive types can't be null...

I just wonder what this is creating...

Comment: 0 is not null, is 0
Should create an array of size 1 with value 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  `new int[]` will create an array and initialize with array elements `{1}`.

```
new int[]{1,}; // Create an array of int of size 1 with value 1 as a first element
```

if you print the length of `int[] i`. Size will be print 1. because last `comma` is ignored if no further element found.

```
System.out.println(i.length); // it will print 1
```

Here `i` is a reference variable which holds the `array` Onject. while `new int[]` will only responsible for creating `Array`.

Thank You

Comment: But why couldn't I just simple do `new int[]{0}` or `new int[]{1}`?

Comment: you are doing the same here ? then what exactly your question is ??  @RoiEX

Comment: Whats the difference between `new int[]{0}` and `new int[]{0,}` ?

Comment: second statement `new int [] (0,)` will automatically ignore the last comma expression if there is no such element present further in the list.

@RoiEX

Answer (score 2):

This would create an array of length 1 which is equivalent to

```
int[] i = new int[]{0};
```

The last comma will be ignored as specified in [JLS §10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array
>   initializer and is ignored.